# Pyinstaller closes my program when I try to open it

Tags: python, python-3.x

Every time I open my program after using pyinstaller it closes immediately. I have tried to add a line where you have to press a button to exit the program, but that doesn't work. I have also tried running pyinstaller usin --onefile or -F, but neither produced a different result. Can someone help me diagnose why this is?

Here is my code:

```
import pytube
from pytube import YouTube
from moviepy.editor import *
import os.path
import os
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
from pytube import monostate
from pytube import streams
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('BluePurple')

layout = [[sg.Text('Please insert a Youtube URL or Youtube Playlist URL:'), sg.Text(size=(15,1), key=('Output'))],
        [sg.Text('Youtube video', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText('')],
        [sg.Text('Download location', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText('')],
        [sg.Button('Download Video')],
        [sg.Text('Youtube music playlist', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText('')],
        [sg.Text('Download location', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText('')],
        [sg.Button('Download Playlist')],
        [sg.Text('Youtube Music video', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText('')],
        [sg.Text('Download location', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText('')],
        [sg.Button('Download Song'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

window = sg.Window('Pattern 2B', layout)


while True:  # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    #video1, = values[0]
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Download Video':
        # Update the "output" text element to be the value of "input" element

        yt = YouTube(values[0])

        #Show details
        print("Title: ",yt.title)
        print("Number of views: ",yt.views)
        print("Length of video: ",yt.length)
        print("Rating of video: ",yt.rating)

        #Get the highest resolution
        ys = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()

        #Download
        l=(values[1])
        print("Downloading...")

        ys.download(l)
        print("Download completed! ")

    if event == "Download Playlist":
        url=(values[2])
        #Converter
        playlist = pytube.Playlist(url)
        for video in playlist.videos:
            filename = video.streams.get_audio_only().download(values[3])
            clip = AudioFileClip(filename)
            clip.write_audiofile(filename[:-4] + ".mp3")
            os.remove(filename)
            clip.close()

    if event == "Download Song":

        url=(values[4])

        yt=YouTube(url)
    
        #Download
        filename = yt.streams.get_audio_only().download(values[5])
        print("Downloading...")
        clip = AudioFileClip(filename)
        clip.write_audiofile(filename[:-4] + ".mp3")
        clip.close()
        os.remove(filename)
        print("Download completed! ")

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with pytube, try using alternate libs like youtube_dl or anything else instead of pytube.

Comment: I will give it a try.

Comment: How do I use YouTube-dl to download a playlist in mp3 format and choose where to save it? Like I figured out how to do so with single videos, using this website https://ostechnix.com/youtube-dl-tutorial-with-examples-for-beginners/, but I don't understand how to do it with it a playlist. Do you have any ideas?